# Checkmark error in amsmath

Tags: symbols, amsmath, texworks

[This page](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/latex/amssymbols.pdf) says that `amsmath` supports the `\checkmark` symbol.  However, when I try to implement this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\checkmark$

\end{document}
```

TeXWorks gives me the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
recently read> \checkmark
```

What could be the problem here? Thanks all.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{amssymb}` and [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The package `amsmath` is useful, but the symbols are loaded by `amssymb`. That page is wrong.

Comment: The site http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html let's you see which package is needed for which symbol, see [How to look up a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol), too. Yeah, and +1 for a perfect Minimal (non)-Working Example!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

that page is mistaken.  all the symbol names listed there are from `amsfonts`.

the original implementation of `amsmath` (then called `amstex.sty` after the non-latex
original) loaded `amsfonts`, but `amsmath` does not.  from the file `amsmath.dtx`:

```
%    A \latex/ package named \pkg{amstex} was created in 1988--1989 by
%    adapting \fn{amstex.tex} for use within \latex/. The \pkg{amsmath}
%    package is the successor of the \pkg{amstex} package. It was
%    substantially overhauled to integrate it with \latex/2e, which
%    arrived on the scene in 1994. It provides more or less the same
%    features, but there are quite a few organizational differences as
%    well as some new features and bug fixes. For example, the
%    \pkg{amstex} package automatically loaded the \pkg{amsfonts}
%    package, but the \pkg{amsmath} package does not. At the present
%    time (November 1999) user-level documentation of the commands
%    provided here is found in the AMSmath Users' Guide,
%    \fn{amsldoc.tex}.
```

so it's necessary to `\usepackage{amsfonts}` to get access to `\checkmark`.
most of the rest of the cited page specifies `amssymb`, which is correct; `amssymb`
loads `amsfonts` automatically, so it's not necessary to specify both if the
additional symbols are needed.

do you know who is responsible for that page?  it would be polite to let them
know it should be corrected/updated.